# Speed reading on iPad

Tags: ipad, books, kindle

I want to speed read on I pad. I have Kindle app and iBooks installed. In order to do that I need to split the screen by two vertical lines so as per image.

[image]

Is there any software I can use for that can split the screen like that?

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the lines in the screen or use a screen protector and draw the lines with a marker. There are removable screen protectors so you can use it when you read and remove once you're done fast reading.